# How to change variable value in python with if condition

Tags: python

How can I change python variable value with if.
so like we have a=5, and there we have an input b, if b =5, i want the program to change a to 3.
This is the program I tried to make but it didnt work, hope you have solution.

```
a=5
b=int(input())
if b==5:
    a==3

print(a)
```

Comment: Remove one of the equal signs in the line `a==3`. `=` means to assign, `==` means to compare.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
b = int(input())
if b == 5:
    a = 3

print(a)
```

If you want to set a new variable only use one equal sign not two.

Answer (score 1):

you need to change the 4th line from `a==3` to `a=3`when you use double '=' you are comparing and the result is boolean (true or false) and when you use just a single '=' your are assigning a value to something.

For example:
`a = 3==4 print(a)`
This will output FALSE, since 3 doesn't equal 4 and that value was assigned to variable `a`